# CakePHP 3 Query with multiple joins ORM

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

What I want to do:

- Join multiple tables.
- Read data.
- If possible, create array of the data with multiple dimensions.

I have a database like: 
Table articles, tags, users, categories

JOIN:

- Articles needs an inner join with tags. (Many to many relation)
- Tags inner join with users. (Many to one relation)
- Tags inner join with categories. (Many to one relation)

My query so far:

```
private function findAllArticleRelatedStuff() {
$query = $articles->find();
$query->innerJoinWith('Tags', function ($q) {
    $q->innerJoinWith('Users');
    $q->innerJoinWith('Categories');
    return $q;
});
$query->select(['Articles.articlename', 'Tags.tagname', 'Users.username', 'Categories.categoriename']);
return $query;
```

}

I want to select the articlesname, tagsname, usersname, categoriesname and first print it (in the view, 've already done that via set()).

```
foreach($query as $article) {
    debug($article->articlename); // works fine

    foreach($article as $tag) {
        debug($tag->tagname); // no output, no error

        // other foreach loops or something...
    }
}
```

I think I made a stupid mistake here.

And can you give me an advise for creating an array of these values? I thought I read about some array method in CakePHP.

Edit: (Found the solution)
I didn't read out the data correctly:

```
foreach($query as $article) {
    debug($article->articlenamename);
    debug($article->_matchingData["Tags"]["tagname"]);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to define relationship among `articles` and `Tags`, `Users` & `Categories` ?

Comment: Jup, when I use a 'normal' query it works correct.

Comment: use contain along with innerjoinwith to get associated data http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain

Comment: Check the edit, I've just found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try debug($article->tag->tagname);

Comment: Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object